# Non-null variable is being called null?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

```
protected var categoryXML:XML;
protected var categoryArr:ArrayCollection;
protected var categoryList:IList;

for (var i:int=0;i<getLength(categoryXML.category);i++) {
   trace(categoryXML.category[i].name);
   categoryArr[i] = categoryXML.category[i].name;
}
```

I'm having trouble with this bit of code...

The trace here works great, and I get the response I expect, but when I try to add it to the categoryArr variable, I get yelled at and told it's null.

What could cause the difference here?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say, "I get yelled at and told it's null.", is _it's_ referring to `categoryArr` or something else?  As a rule of thumb, if you're confused about an error, you should include the error message directly in your post.

Comment: This snippet is very incomplete: you show declarations for your variables and a for loop which is obviously located in some method somewhere, but don't show/explain where/how any of these variables are instantiated. Please include more code so we get a better idea of what's going wrong and can help you out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try to create your `ArrayCollection` : `categoryArr = new ArrayCollection();` ?

Answer (score 2):

So, if you are getting that there is a null reference at that line, it is because categoryArr is probably null.  You need to initialize it, like @www0x0k suggested.

I will also suggest that you probably don't want to use indexes in this way.  It assumes too much about the length of the particular ArrayCollection without any bounds checking.  Consider code like this instead:

```
categoryArr = new ArrayCollection();
for each(var category in categoryXML.category) {
   trace(category.name);
   categoryArr.addItem(category.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I just wasn't initializing the ArrayCollection.